# Whether traffic is encrypted between containers on the same host machine vs. scaled services

Tags: docker

I'm learning about SSL and encryption between docker containers for two particular scenarios.  In both scenarios Traefik container is a reverse proxy between the external world and a NodeJS API container.  The NodeJS API simply writes a record to the mongo database container.  In both scenarios, Traefik will use SSL to encrypt any traffic between itself and the external world.  I think traffic between Traefik and the NodeJS API will happen in plain text because the NodeJS API will not use an SSL certificate.  And I think the data between the NodeJS API and the database will also be in plain text.

Here is a `docker-compose` file that I have, which I think is described by my statements above.

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5.4
    command:
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik/dynamic_conf"
      - "--providers.file.watch=true"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:3001"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./templates/ssl/:/certs/:ro
      - ./traefik.config.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic_conf/conf.yml:ro
    networks:
      - mynet
  api:
    image: johnlai2004/swarm:latest
    environment:
      - "DB=${STACK_NAME}_db"
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}_api.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}_api.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}_api.rule=Host(`${APP_HOST}`)"
        - "traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME}_api.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynet

  db:
    image: mongo:4.0.3
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
```

Then I start things up with these commands:

```
docker swarm init;
docker network create --driver overlay mynet;

STACK_NAME=mystack1 APP_HOST=mystack1.example.com docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack1;
```

Question 1: All the code above runs on one single host machine.  Would many developers be concerned about the unencrypted traffic that happens between Traefik and the NodeJS API and the unencrypted traffic between NodeJS API and Mongo database?  I assume the traffic in these two situations are happening within a virtual docker network that is not easily accessible to attackers from the outside world unless the attacker already has access to the host machine? Are these reasonable assumptions?

Question 2: Let's say I created a second host machine that is located in a different city.  I run the `docker swarm join` so that this second machine becomes a worker node.  Then I run the command `docker service scale api=4` which creates four more instances of the api container, some of which will run on this second host machine.   In this situation, will attackers have an easy time sniffing the traffic between Traefik and the API and sniffing the traffic between the API and the Database?  And will attackers see the traffic in plain text?